# unable to connect cloud sql from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am new to GCP. I created a cloud-SQL instance (PostgreSQL 14) and tried to connect to it from the app engine.

I am using the following code on github.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/9d4343d0845d6e20e0b08d1242c38aaaf0d9c075/appengine/standard_python3/cloudsql

main_postgres.py-> as my main file

I updated the connection information in the app.yaml file according to the instance and database I created. I did not make any other changes to the main_postgres.py file.

I deployed app engine in the directory with main_postgres.py
After deploying when I go to the link it says :
[image]

I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to connect? (Do not add links to code, copy and paste it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to replicate the github link you provided. I solved it by renaming the `main_postgres.py` file to `main.py`. Here's the screenshot of the output link:
[image]

Comment: my reputation is 11 it needs to be 15 to be able to upvote. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This issue dont seems related to DB but your application configuration.
check errors by running this in cloud shell when you hit appengine url.

gcloud app logs tail